# Unable to run Java program from Perl/PHP script

Tags: java, php, perl, centos7

I'm trying to run an external script

And I get the following message:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#...

system("java -version");

#...
```

Error in log

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
> space for 2097152KB object heap

CentOS

```
user@node ~ $ java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

In google search informs to increase the memory size

java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -version

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#...

system("java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -version");

#...
```

Error persists!

```
user@node ~ $ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8257536       50788     8030816        1056      175932     8205692
Swap:       4128768           0     4128768

user@node ~ $ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1030456
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 524290
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 4194304
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I see the same error persists if I try to run external command via PHP

```
<?php
     echo exec('java -version');
?>
```

Error running via browser: Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes

```
user@node ~ $ php -v
PHP 8.0.5 (cli) (built: May  3 2021 06:17:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

user@node ~ $ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8257536       50788     8030816        1056      175932     8205692
Swap:       4128768           0     4128768

user@node ~ $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: looks like there is not enough memory left for java... maybe try with smaller memory like `java -Xmx1024M -version`  (1024MB - or even less)

Comment: @LiandroCos if you need to add detail, please [edit] your question, don't use comments. They're rather hard to read right now.

Comment: java -Xmx1024M -version

_Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap_

Comment: Sounds like you don't have enough memory to run both `java` and `perl`